# extract literal from scala pattern for clarity

Tags: scala

I have a Conent envelope where the Message is a string that may be base64 encoded and if so possibly gzipped also.  The message method below handles the case where Message is both encoded and compressed.  However, for clarity's sake, it would be nice to extract the pattern somehow, does scala offer any facility for doing so?

```
  case class Content(Message: String,
                     MessageAttributes: Option[MessageAttributes])

  case class MessageAttributes(compression: Option[MessageAttribute],
                               encoding: Option[MessageAttribute])

  case class MessageAttribute(Type: String, Value: String)
```

What I would like to do (but withBase64EncodingAndCompression in the pattern will just shadow my val, of course):

```
  def message: String = {
    val withBase64EncodingAndCompression =
      Some(MessageAttributes(Some(MessageAttribute("String", "gzip")), Some(MessageAttribute("String", "base64"))))
    parsed.extract[Content] match {
      case Content(message, withBase64EncodingAndCompression) =>
        val decoded = Base64.getDecoder.decode(message)
        GZIPCompression.decompress(decoded)
      case _ => message
    }
  }
```

What I have to do:

```
  def message: String = {
    parsed.extract[Content] match {
      case Content(message, Some(MessageAttributes(Some(MessageAttribute("String", "gzip")), Some(MessageAttribute("String", "base64"))))) =>
        val decoded = Base64.getDecoder.decode(message)
        GZIPCompression.decompress(decoded)
      case _ => message
    }
```

I have adapted Vitalii Honta's answer from below.  The names are different, and I have removed my infinite recursion, but this shows what I was after-- to move as much of the pattern as possible outside the case clause.

```
 def sqsEnvelopeMessage: String = {
    val sqsEnvelope = SqsEnvelope(parsed)
    val withBase64EncodingAndCompression = Some(SqsEnvelopeAttributes(Some(SqsEnvelopeAttribute("String", "base64")), Some(SqsEnvelopeAttribute("String", "gzip"))))
    sqsEnvelope match {
      case SqsEnvelope(message, `withBase64EncodingAndCompression`) =>
        val decoded = Base64.getDecoder.decode(message)
        GZIPCompressionUtil.decompress(decoded)
      case SqsEnvelope(message, _) =>
        message
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have defined your pattern somewhere:

```
// no need to wrap MessageAttributes into Some here
val withBase64EncodingAndCompression =
   MessageAttributes(Some(MessageAttribute("String", "gzip")), Some(MessageAttribute("String", "base64")))
```

If I understood correctly, you can rewrite your code using special syntax which Scala provides:

```
  def message: String = {
    parsed.extract[Content] match {
      case Content(message, Some(`withBase64EncodingAndCompression`)) =>
        // your code handling message
      case _ => message
    }
  }
```

Using backquotes (``) in `match` is equivalent to comparing using `==` operator:

```
  def message: String = {
    parsed.extract[Content] match {
      case Content(message, Some(x)) if x == withBase64EncodingAndCompression =>
        // your code handling message
      case _ => message
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I  was after-- thank you.  I was aware of backticks only as a way to use arbitrary strings as variable names, not for pattern substitution.  I have adapted your answer in my post mostly to remove my infinite recursion, but also to make the case clause even shorter by also removing the Some()